# How to reverse a string without using in-built and temporary variables

Tags: c

Reverse operations with out temporary variable and in-built functions like string reverse.

Comment: `with out temporary variable` actually I don't suppose such solutions exist..

Comment: You should let us know why you have these constraints, or we may suspect we're just doing your homework assignment for you

Comment: It is not like that , i encountered such a situation where this can give me a solution in my project.

Comment: Best elaborate what "without temporaries" means exactly. If there is no loophole to exploit, it's probably impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using XOR logic like this:

```
char* rev(char* str)
{
    int end = strlen(str) - 1;
    int start = 0;

    while (start < end)
    {
        str[start] ^= str[end];
        str[end] ^= str[start];
        str[start] ^= str[end];

        ++start;
        --end;
    }

    return str;
}
```